# Why React put quotation mark around paragraph text?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have here a paragraph: https://tikex.com/tikex/form/csatlakozz-vagy-nyerj/jasq/9lek

[image]

Why React put quotion mark round it? If I have a `<a>` in `<p>` it will not get rendered. what can I do?

```js
    return (
        <>
            <div className="container">
                <hr className="space"></hr>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-6">
                        <h1>{post?.captionLeft}</h1>
                        <p style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-line' }}>{post?.textLeft}</p>
                    </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't. That's just the dev tools showing you the boundaries of the node content.

Comment: Or maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: The text in a variable will not be parsed as HTML. If you want to inject HTML you need to use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop. It's not really recomended without sanitizing the content first.

Comment: @super, yes dangerouslySetInnerHTML worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what works: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```js
<p
    style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-line' }}
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: post?.textLeft,
    }}
></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have included every content inside **p** tag with " " quotes this will render everything as text.so you should close quotes before **a** tag. I have created a code sandbox for this Hope this will help  [Code Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-cookies-tyr00o?file=/index.html)